# How can I delete and rewrite rows in a datatable and write them back from a datarow[] array in a different order?

Tags: c#, datarow

I tried saving the datatable rows to a datarow[] array then deleting the datatable rows and rewrite them to the datatable from the datarow[] array in a different order. But when I delete them from the datatable I can't access them from the datarow[] array.

I don't know if I'm doing this correct or if im totally off base but I'm in desperate need of help.

This is what I'm trying to do:

I have a datatable with 8 rows.
I want to be able to somehow loop thru the 8 rows and reorder them based on certain criterias.

For example, my rows have an Invoice number, line number, and Part number as the key fields. Depending on the criteria, I may need rows 6,7,8 to be in the beginning as rows 1,2,3 and shift the rest down.

If anyone has an Idea please reply....this is an urgent issue.

thank you,

Sam

Comment: It really doesnt matter which row is where in the database. You have to use OrderBy to get the rows in specific order.

Comment: You wanna have the rows in different order? So rows number 6,7,8 on top, then follow 1,2,3 and then 9,10,11 and so on... I am right?

Comment: If it's so urgent, get paid help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a DataRow:

```
var dr = table.Rows[0];
```

and then delete the row from the table, `dr` will also be deleted. It's the same row. That explains your problem.

As for the solution, don't reorder rows in a DataTable. Instead, add another column called `RowOrder`, modify it to change the order, and then sort the DataTable based on that column, as @mperrenoud03 has shown you:

table.DefaultView.Sort = "RowOrder";

and use the default view.

Answer (score 1):

Use the DataView to view the rows because it can be sorted like this.

```
dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "columnNameA, columnNameB desc";
```

Then bind the list, whatever you're using, to the DataView.

Oh and here's some documentation on the [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx) property.

Comment: @hmakled Did this take care of the issue for you? If so please mark it as the answer for myself and everybody else on the community.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like this:

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Invoice", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Line", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Part", typeof(string));

        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
            table.Rows.Add("Invoice " + i, i, "Part " + i);
        //reorder them:
        int[] orders = { 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        DataTable table2 = table.Clone();
        DataRow row;
        for (int i = 0; i < orders.Length; i++)
        {
            row = table2.NewRow();
            row["Invoice"] = table.Rows[orders[i]]["Invoice"];
            row["Line"] = table.Rows[orders[i]]["Line"];
            row["Part"] = table.Rows[orders[i]]["Part"];
            table2.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```